# SQL server SELECT with join performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry about the saga here but am trying to explain everything.
We have 2 databases that I would like to join some tables in.
1 database holds sales data from various different stores/sites.  This database is quite large (over 3mill rows currently) This table is `ItemSales`
The other holds application data from an in house web app.  These tables are `Departments` and `GroupItems`

I would like to create a query that joins 2 tables from the app database with the sales database table.  This is so we can group some items together for a date range and see the amount sold for example.

My first attempt was (`DealId` being the variable that it is grouped on in the App):

```
SELECT d.Id,  d.ItemNo, d.UnitValue, d.NoGST, d.ItemStartDate, d.ItemEndDate,
                         (SELECT        SUM(ItemQty) AS Expr1
                           FROM            Sales.dbo.ItemSales AS s
                           WHERE        (Store = d.SiteId) AND (ItemNo = d.ItemNo) AND (ItemSaleDate >= d.ItemStartDate) AND (ItemSaleDate <= d.ItemEndDate)) AS ItemsSold, Sales.dbo.ItemSales.ItemDesc, Departments.Description 
FROM            Departments INNER JOIN
                     Sales.dbo.ItemSales ON Departments.Id = Sales.dbo.ItemSales.ItemDept RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     GroupItems AS d ON Sales.dbo.ItemSales.ItemNo = d.ItemNo
WHERE        (d.DealId = 11)
GROUP BY d.Id, d.ItemNo, d.UnitValue, d.NoGST, d.ItemStartDate, d.ItemEndDate, ItemDesc, Departments.Description, d.SiteId
ORDER BY d.Id
```

This does exactly what I want which is:
-Give me all the details from the `GroupItems` table (UnitValue, ItemStartDate, ItemEndDate etc)
-Gives me the SUM() on the `ItemQty` column for the amount sold (plus the description etc)
-Returns NULL for something with no sales for the period

It is VERY slow though.  To the point that if the `GroupItems` table has more than about 7 items in it, it times out.

Second attempt has been:

```
SELECT d.Id,  d.ItemNo, d.UnitValue, d.NoGST, d.ItemStartDate, d.ItemEndDate, SUM(ItemQty) AS ItemsSold, Sales.dbo.ItemSales.ItemDesc, Departments.Description
FROM            Departments INNER JOIN
                     Sales.dbo.ItemSales ON Departments.Id = Sales.dbo.ItemSales.ItemDept RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     GroupItems AS d ON Sales.dbo.ItemSales.ItemNo = d.ItemNo
WHERE        (Store = d.SiteId) AND (d.DealId = 11)  AND (Sales.dbo.ItemSales.ItemSaleDate >= d.ItemStartDate) AND (Sales.dbo.ItemSales.ItemSaleDate <= d.ItemEndDate)
GROUP BY d.Id, d.ItemNo, d.UnitValue, d.NoGST, d.ItemStartDate, d.ItemEndDate, ItemDesc, Departments.Description
ORDER BY d.Id
```

This is very quick and does not time out but does not return the NULLs for no sales items in the `ItemSales` table.  This is a problem as we need to see nothing or 0 for a no sales item otherwise people will think we forgot to check that item.

Can someone help me come up with a query please that returns everything from the `GroupItems` table, shows the SUM() of items sold and doesn't time out?  I have also tried a SELECT x WHERE EXISTS (Subquery) but this also didn't return the NULLs for me but I may have had that one wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want everything from `GroupItems` regardless of the sales, use it as the base of the query and then use `left outer join`s from there.  Something along these lines:

```
SELECT  GroupItems.Id,  GroupItems.ItemNo, GroupItems.UnitValue, GroupItems.NoGST, 
        GroupItems.ItemStartDate, GroupItems.ItemEndDate, 
        Sales.ItemDesc,
        SUM(ItemQty) AS SumOfSales,
        Departments.Description
FROM GroupItems
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tempSales AS Sales ON 
                            Sales.ItemNo = GroupItems.ItemNo
                        AND Sales.Store = GroupItems.SiteId
                        AND Sales.ItemSaleDate >= GroupItems.ItemStartDate 
                        AND Sales.ItemSaleDate <= GroupItems.ItemEndDate
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Departments ON Departments.Id = Sales.ItemDept 
WHERE GroupItems.DealId = 11
GROUP BY GroupItems.Id,  GroupItems.ItemNo, GroupItems.UnitValue, GroupItems.NoGST, 
         GroupItems.ItemStartDate, GroupItems.ItemEndDate, 
         Sales.ItemDesc,
         SUM(ItemQty) AS SumOfSales,
         Departments.Description   
ORDER BY GroupItems.Id
```

Comment: that works quite quickly but still doesn't show the No Sale items.  I'm guessing (from what I have read) this is because the `Store` filter is on the RIGHT table and if there is no sales on a line then that filter can't apply?

Comment: Even with the modification of putting the dates in the join clause?  You may need to refresh this page to see my answer edit.  I believe that should do it for you.

Comment: Sorry, after the edit, the query now times out.  I have tried playing with indexes as well on the Sales table since it is so big but it has had little effect

Comment: yes, from Management Studio.  For now I have been running them from there as it saves changing the code and testing there.  When a query starts to look good I put it into the code but have found if it times out in Management Studio it will time out in the code as well. I know I could adjust the time out but the app will end up being unusable if pages take too long to load

Comment: still times out sorry, there is also 2x `AND Sales.Store = GroupItems.SiteId` in that example but i'm assuming that was an error so removed.

Comment: Still times out sorry.  is it because it is trying to copy 3.2 million rows into the temp table?  Even grouped it would still be a lot of rows?

Comment: Sure, but with proper indexing, that should be a breeze (3 million rows should barely make SQL Server sweat). And there is no real performance penalty for joining to another database to pull data as long as they are both on the same sever.  I would revisit your indexes on the Sales table.  Use Query Analyzer to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Can I ask for advice then on proper indexing please as everything I have tried hasn't worked.  I will also provide details on the Analyser

Comment: With your suggestion of the Query Analyser and some Indexes, I went with your previous example with the Outer Joins and it performs very well and returns all NULLs, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the INNER JOIN to Sales.dbo.ItemSales into a LEFT OUTER JOIN to Sales.dbo.ItemSales and changing the RIGHT OUTER JOIN to GroupItems into an INNER JOIN to GroupItems fix your issue?

Comment: no sorry, that still gives me only the items with sales attached to them (using the 2nd query).  The first one no longer times out but does double up some results (I have found this is because people have changed the ItemDesc over the life of the product so each change of the name results in a double up-may be a whole other issue).  It also still takes just over 50 seconds to run, maybe this is as fast as it will get?